# Android Studio installation in a customized location

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to install android studio Completely in a customized location.
I don't want to put anything in 'C drive'.
Like--
.gradle,  .android,  AndroidStudio3.1,  AndroidStudioProjects, Sdk

All of these in a new location 'E drive'

How can I do this? So that I can avoid reinstallation of Android Studio when windows set up is done again.

Answer (score 0):

While installing On Start android studio will ask you. You need Change location over here You must have at least 500mb free space

[image: Check out This]

Comment: I have done this. But still .gradle .android files are creating in 'C drive' @vinit-poojary

Comment: when you start project you can specify where to store your project